# Правильное написание временных промежутков

Tags: даты

Можно ли так написать временной промежуток: 23–24.05.2006, 02.08-22.11.2009?

Comment: в числовых интервалах дат, представленных цифрами (дд.мм.гггг). В данном случае лучше использовать предлоги: с 23.07.2014 по 30.08.2014. При этом некорректно писать, например, с 23.07 по 30.08.2014, 23.07–30.08.2014 или с 11 по 15.08.2014. В таком случае названия месяцев лучше писать словами: с 23 июля по 30 августа 2014 г. или с 11 по 15 августа 2014 г.;

Comment: https://pishuverno.ru/kak-pishutsya-intervaly-dat/#:~:text=Используются%20тире%20и%20дефисы%20и,«года»%20уместно%20заменять%20сокращением%20«гг.»

Comment: Вот еще один источник, какой-то главред отвечает, думаю можно верить): https://bureau.ru/soviet/20210425/

Comment: @Буратино Огромное спасибо!